# What does Neruda mean when he says ‘Maybe January light will consume My heart with its cruel Ray.’?

Tags: meaning, poetry, spanish-language, pablo-neruda

I’ve been a fan of Neruda for a while now. In his [Sonnet LXVI: I Do Not Love You Except Because I Love You](https://allpoetry.com/Sonnet-LXVI:-I-Do-Not-Love-You-Except-Because-I-Love-You), he says:

> Maybe January light will consume
>   My heart with its cruel
>   Ray, stealing my key to true calm.

I do not understand these verses. Especially why does he mention January specifically? And what does he mean by January light?

Comment: It's worth noting that this poem was [originally in Spanish](http://www.neruda.uchile.cl/obra/obraciensonetos5.html). A blogger has provided [an alternative English translation](http://www.nicoledeguzman.com/blog/pablo-neruda-sonnet-lxvi-translation/) without those odd line breaks. It's even more worth noting that January in Spanish is "enero", which appears at the end of the line to rhyme with "entero" (entire). But a good poet should have more reason for wording choice than just "because it rhymes", so that can't be the full answer.

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks! But I still don’t get the relevance of January!

Answer (score 2):

Well Neruda was Chilean and Chile is in the southern hemisphere. Therefore January is the hottest month by far and when the sun shines more cruelly.

I am not Chilean but I am from the same latitude in Argentina. As January is the hottest month it is usually the month with the brightest light also.

Comment: Is "January light" ("la luz de enero") a common saying in that part of the world for intense sunlight?

Comment: @Randal'Thor That does make a lot of sense in the context of the verse. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As in English, the first month of the Spanish year is named after Janus, the Greek double-faced god, who looks behind at the past year and forward toward the new. Janus was also the god of thresholds, liminal spaces and doors, likely accounting for all the back and forth in the narrator’s words and the reference to the “key.”

Some more information from wikipedia, on Janus, may also clarify some of the questions and comments above:

> While the fundamental nature of Janus is debated, in most modern scholars' view the god's functions may be seen as being organized around a single principle: presiding over all beginnings and transitions, whether abstract or concrete, sacred or profane.[15] Interpretations concerning the god's fundamental nature either limit it to this general function or emphasize a concrete or particular aspect of it (identifying him with light[16] the sun,[17] the moon,[18] time,[19] movement,[20] the year,[21] doorways,[22] bridges[23] etc.) or else see in the god a sort of cosmological principle, interpreting him as a uranic deity.[24]

Comment: What's your specific answer as to the meaning of "January light"?

Comment: The meaning of “January light” was present in my answer till you decided to “edit” it.  Now I have to go back to my earlier answer and get the quotation back, because it seems to have been lost in the “rollback.”  Thanks.

Comment: ? I didn't mean to remove any information in my edit. I simply deleted several numbers in brackets, which looked to be pointing to citations that were not present in the quote.

Comment: Then It’s not a problem.  I was a bit annoyed because somehow in one of the edits the quotation with the information on Janus as sun or light got dropped. Once that occurred, my answer became useless.

Comment: That appears to have been an edit by you: see [Revision 4](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/18163/revisions); it is a rollback to Revision 1.

Comment: Yes, you are technically right.  It was my hasty attempt to bring the full quotation back that, instead of bringing it back, reverted back to my original.  I was annoyed that someone had removed stuff from a direct quotation. Editors, in my opinion, ought not to do this without acknowledging it: a direct quotation should stand as it is found, unless the original speaker made a spelling error or obvious mistake, and even then the change ought to be acknowledged.

Comment: Wikipedia's citation marks technically aren't part of the actual quotation; they function more like disconnected endnotes than anything else. The only reason they're in your quotation is you copied directly off the page, instead of copying just the words. (though I would consider it fine to leave the citation marks in if they retained their formatting and links) Feel free to join me in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room) for a more extended discussion.

Comment: No thanks, I’ve already wasted enough time and energy getting my answer  back to what I wanted to convey.